# How to protect HTTPGET methods in MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, antiforgerytoken

I have gone through many blog articles describing how to validate users in our web applications using [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] attribute. But this has limitations such as can be used only with HTTPPOST methods. My requirement is I have a MVC 5 application which returning sensitive data (Ex: bank statements) using HTTPGET methods. How to authorize/protect these action methods from anonymous users ?.
I want to write a token based authorization mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct - the ValidateAntiForgeryToken mitigates against Cross-Site-REquest-Forgery (CSRF). It is specific to POST's, as it can correlate the a response issued by a server, and the HTML posted from a user. There is no concept of CSRF for GETs.

To protect GETS from anonymous users, use the `[Authorize]` attribute on any methods that you require users to be logged into the websites. If they are not, they will be redirected to the login section, as configured in your web.config.

Comment: Thanks Dominic. My problem is users are assigned to dynamic roles which has set of functions. Roles are assigning user. Therefore i cant mark it as [Authorize(Role="Adminstrator")]

Comment: @Ajith: This will require users to be logged in as a minimum, and therefore deny anonymous access.